# How to reorder the result set

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this result set in a given table. The query which I used was `Select ID, Name, Sequence FROM MyTable order by Sequence`

```
ID | Name | Sequence
1    Ryan   001
2    Setli  001
3    Ryan   002
4    Setli  002
```

However, what I want my result set to be is this:

```
ID | Name | Sequence
1    Ryan   001
2    Setli  002
3    Ryan   001
4    Setli  002
```

How do I fix my query to achieve this result set?

Comment: `Setli..001` and `Setli..002` have the same ID of 2?

Comment: You are asking to change the very records themselves?

Comment: `order by` shorts the result straightly...

Comment: Hi, on what basis do you need this separation!

Comment: you can try this query for your output : 
`Select ID, Name, Sequence FROM MyTable ORDER BY Name,ID ASC`

Answer (score 0):

To get the results for what you have described you would do the following:

```
Select ID, Name, Sequence FROM MyTable ORDER BY ID ASC
```